# Complete an url wtih the data given in boxes and go to that url

Tags: javascript, html, url

My workmates and I use the link below a couple of times in a day by clicking several pages to finally get this link:
`http://eharita.mamak.bel.tr/imararsiv/test.aspx?f_ada=36391&f_parsel=4`

What i want to do is, after `test.aspx?_ada=` you see `36391` this is my first number and `&f_parsel= 4` this is the second one.

I want to create an HTML which consist of 2 boxes and a submit, sent button, in the very first box i want to write down a number (in the example it is : 36391) and in the second box another number (in the example it is : 4)  and after that i ll click on Submit or Send button and this action will take me to the URL of
`http://eharita.mamak.bel.tr/imararsiv/test.aspx?f_ada=36391&f_parsel=4`

Maybe its easy or not but as a civil engineer i don't know how to make an HTML page like that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy, you just need a basic form.

```
<form action="http://eharita.mamak.bel.tr/imararsiv/test.aspx" method="GET">
   <input type="text" name="f_ada" > <br>
   <input type="text" name="f_parsel"> <br>
   <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can try it out here http://jsfiddle.net/ea6heach/

Comment: I can't believe that its that easy. Thanks for your quick and simple asnwer. Now i'm improving my custom homepage

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form action="http://eharita.mamak.bel.tr/imararsiv/test.aspx">
        <input type="text" name="f_ada"/><br>
        <input type="text" name="f_parcel"/><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

The demo doesn't work because Stackoverflow doesn't allow HTML redirecting but this is the idea of a simple form.

Answer (score 1):

Following form write in particular html file.

```
<form action="action_page.php">
  First number<br>
  <input type="text" name="first_val" >
  <br>
  Second number<br>
  <input type="text" name="second_val">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

//following code write in the 'action_page.php' file.

```
<?php
 //in the action_page.php file write following code
 if(isset($_GET['first_val']) && isset($_GET['second_val'])
{
?f_ada=36391&f_parsel=4
$url = 'http://eharita.mamak.bel.tr/imararsiv/test.aspx/';
$url .= '?f_ada='.$_GET['first_val']&f_parsel['second_val'];
header('Location: $url);
}
?>
```